# How can I change the generic type in child-classes in Java

Tags: java, generics

How can I change the generic type in child-classes. I know, that i can override method load(); But i want to make the universal method for all children. 
I have abstract super class

```
public abstract class Vehicle <T extends Human> {
    T t;
    private final int maxPassengers;
    private Set<T> currentPassengers = new HashSet<>();

    public Vehicle(int maxPassengers) {
       this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
    }

    public void load (T human) throws ToManyPassangersExeption {
        if (currentPassengers.size()<maxPassengers)
            currentPassengers.add(human);
        else
            throw new ToManyPassangersExeption();
    }
}
```

load() realize loading Human to vehicle. I have different types of Human. For example:

```
public class Policeman extends Human {
    }
```

In my class PoliceCar, i what to load only Policemen.

```
public class PoliceCar <T extends Policeman> extends Vehicle {
    T t;

    public PoliceCar() {
        super(5);
    }
}
```

Using this code, i can load all instanceof Human to PoliceCar.

How can i load only Policeman in PoliceCar without Overriding method load()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `PoliceCar` type with a non-raw superclass:

```
class PoliceCar<T extends Policeman> extends Vehicle<T>
```

Then the `load` method will require a `T` parameter, where `T` is a subclass of `Policeman`.

See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Just `PoliceCar extends Vehicle<Policeman>` may be good enougth too.

Comment: @Zefick indeed. But the critical bit is adding the type parameter to `Vehicle`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now its Work!